# C++ Can I make boost::asio connection socket without timer?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, connection-timeout

I have a window server socket and a Linux client socket. Client connect to server and send a message. After, the server will call a external executable. The problem is : when server is not available, Client is blocking with timeout at connect function, But I don't want it. I hope if the connection is not made, client socket will be closed straight away.

Somebody can give me some advice?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: socket.connect(Iterator iterator)
When server is down, Client is blocked on this stat with some timeout. I hope to remove this timeout or set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Pseudo-Code ahead.

You can do that. But it is not as straight forward as you might hope.
You need to use `async_connect()` from your client to not block. Then you also need a `deadline_timer` set to whatever timeout you deem appropriate. Zero will not work, you need to give the `async_connect()` some time. But i guess one or two seconds should be fine.

The timers handler will then have to `cancel()` all async operations on the socket (you need to make sure that is only the connect, use more sockets if needed).

Mind the socket will not be closed by that. Ideally you will close it in the handler of the `async_connect` whenever the passed error_code indicates a negative result. For example, if it was canceled, the handler will be called with OPERATION_ABORTED as error_code.

Of course, if you check only for that, you could as well `close()` the socket in the timers handler after the `cancel()`. But that would leave you with an open socket whenever the `async_connect` failed for some other reason.

I would assume from your question that you want your socket to get closed whenever the `async_connect()` passes any error_code but SUCCESS. And SUCCESS is the only error_code implicitly converted to 0 when used as a boolean, so checking for that in your handler is easy. ^^

Do not forget to cancel the `deadline_timer` in the handler of the `async_connect()` and to make sure the timers handler was not called with OPERATION_ABORTED before it closes the socket. ^^